# Dimensional problem in using train test split

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, train-test-split

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

predictors=data.drop(['target'],axis=1)
targets=data['target']
train_x,test_x,train_y,test_y=train_test_split(predictors,targets,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
```

shape of `train_x` is `(242,13)`
shape of `train_y` is `(242,)`
shape of `test_x` is `(61,13)`
shape of `test_y` is `(61,)`

dataset has 303 examples and i/p has 13 features

if I try

`np.reshape(train_y,(-1,1))`

It says data must be 1 dimensional

I want train_y shape to be `(242,1)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the reshape method like so

```
train_y = train_y.reshape(train_y.shape[0], 1)
```

But I'd suggest reshaping `targets` so that both train_y and test_y are of shape (x, 1)

```
targets = data['target']
targets = targets.reshape(targets.shape[0], 1)
```

After this you can use train test split

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gfn0x_DywKvMpsgBCAqEi5liUsbCmz2S/view?usp=sharing                 this is the dataset

Comment: from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

predictors=data.drop(['target'],axis=1)
targets=data['target']
train_x,test_x,train_y,test_y=train_test_split(predictors,targets,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
print(targets.shape)

Comment: print(train_x.shape)
print(train_y.shape)
print(test_x.shape)
print(test_y.shape)

Comment: it will be really helpful if you check it once!

Comment: I've further edited my answer to make it more clear. Let me know if you're still having problems

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new axis with `np.newaxis`:

```
train_y = train_y[:, np.newaxis]
```

It does the same as `train_y.reshape(train_y.shape[0], 1)`, so I guess it is just a matter of personal preference which way you choose.